# @class getting added even though it's the defaultImpl

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using Jackson (the JSON/Object mapper), let's say I have the following interface and classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(defaultImpl = Duck.class, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
public interface Animal {
}

public class Duck implements Animal {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

public class Park {
    private Animal animal;
    public Animal getAnimal() { return animal; }
    public void setAnimal(Animal animal) { this.animal = animal; }
}
```

And I try to read (deserialize) this piece of JSON:

```
{
    "animal": {
        "name": "Quacky"
    }
}
```

using:

```
Park park = objectMapper.readValue(json, Park.class);
```

It works! Even without any type information (@class or @type) it is able to construct the `Duck` because I specified a `defaultImpl` for the `Animal` interface.

Now I expect the same behaviour when doing it the other way around.

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(park);
```

But instead I get this JSON:

```
{
    "animal": {
        "@class": "com.example.Duck",
        "name": "Quacky"
    }
}
```

It does not seem to respect the `defaultImpl` when serializing! I want the "@class" attribute gone from the output file. Does anyone have any idea of how I can tell Jackson not to add the "@class" attribute for my `Duck`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell Jackson not to include class information for the implementation class. As per the documentation,

> More granular (and powerful) way to define what type information to add, and where, is to use @JsonTypeInfo annotation (and possibly couple of related ones). For example, we could have annotated Animal as follows:
>
> @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
>    class Animal { } 
>   (which, incidentally is equivalent to the default settings for typing).
>
> What does that mean?
>
> - All instances of annotated type and its subtypes use these settings (unless overridden by another annotation)
> - "Type identifier" to use is fully-qualified Java class name (like "org.codehaus.jackson.sample.Animal")
> - Type identifier is to be included as a (meta-)property, along with regular data properties; using name "@class" (default name to use depend on type if: for classes it would be "@class")
> - Use default type resolver (no @JsonTypeResolver added); as well as default type id resolver (no @JsonTypeIdResolver)

Do this by adding an annotation to Duck.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
public class Duck implements Animal {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Failing that, add

```
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", new Version(1,0,0,null));
simpleModule.addSerializer(new JsonSerializer< Duck > {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Duck duck, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("name", duck.getName());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
});
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Unfortunately your solution doesn't work for me. The annotation seems to be ignored. Maybe it is overruled by the @JsonTypeInfo on the superclass (Animal)?

Comment: I looked at the source code, this should have worked. I'll add a custom serializer to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I am using an older version of Jackson or something.

Comment: Could you add the custom serializer to your answer please?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at an old version of the page. Thanks for adding the serializer example! I will try it out later.

Comment: I did take my time with it. It's a little concise, I typically implement in an actual class file when there are a few of them.

Answer (score 0):

Make Duck implement `JsonSerializable`.

```
public class Duck implements Animal, JsonSerializable {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @Override
    public void serialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        // Serialize Duck object
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer)
            throws IOException {
        serialize(gen, serializers);
    }
}
```